# Counting number of items in a matrix according a period of time

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a little issue.

For example, I have a matrix

```
m=[11 1 9 ;
22 2 10; 
33 3 11; 
44 4 14; 
55 1 15;
66 4 20; 
77 1 20; 
88 1 24; 
99 2 24 ]
```

where the first column is the id of a product, the second column is the id of the buyer, and the third is the day of purchase.

I would like to count the number of articles bought by a buyer for a period delta=5 days.

I tried this code but I have an issue: I would like to obtain a final matrix where in the rows i have the ids of the users and in columns the number of articles bought for each period.

```
m=[11 1 9 ;22 2 11; 33 3 10; 44 4 15; 55 1 15;66 4 20; 77 1 20; 88 1 24; 99 2 24 ]
D=m(:,3)
p=0;
delta=5
res=zeros(length(unique(m(:,2))),(div(max(D),delta)))
NbA=zeros(1,length(unique(m(:,2))))
while p<max(D)+1
    p
    pos=find((m(:,3)>=p)& (m(:,3)<p+delta))
    Mtemp=u(pos,:);
    [r c]=size(Mtemp);
    Ustemp=Mtemp(:,2);
    UnUstemp=unique(Ustemp);
    for i=1:length(UnUstemp)clc
         us=UnUstemp(i);
        [n l]=size(find(Ustemp==us));
        NbA(i)=n;
    end    
        res=[res ;NbA];
     p=p+delta; 
end
```

Comment: And that issue is.....?

Comment: i would like to obtain a final matrix where in the rows i have the ids of the users and in coloums the number of articles boughts for each period.

Comment: `div` doesn't appear to be a valid function name.

Comment: Also, `u` is not defined.

Comment: How are the time periods defined? Are they overlapping? How many of them are there? What are they? Could you please show the desired output for the input you provided?

Comment: div is the division function in matlab.
u=m ( the initial matrix)

Comment: for the time periods it is delta= 5 days. They are not overlapping. 
Periods are defined by the max number of day divided by delta.
For the final output i would like to have 
u1 NbAarticleP1 NbAarticleP2 NbAarticleP3
u2 NbAarticleP1 NbAarticleP2 NbAarticleP3

Comment: For the final output i would like to have 
u1 NbAarticleP1 NbAarticleP2 NbAarticleP3
u2 NbAarticleP1 NbAarticleP2 NbAarticleP3
u3 NbAarticleP1 NbAarticleP2 NbAarticleP3